# Google cloud platform - OAuth Publishing issue : a scope that I really don't access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I developed a calendar-related app with google calendar apis,
Everything works just fine in development mode.

And I tried to publish this app in my console,
The Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team kept rejecting and claimed that my app access this scope:
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds
How my application is able to access the scope (calendar/feeds) if it had not been submitted in my console as a scope to access?
And I can't find any documents and clues to add this scope in the console.

And all the scopes I used in calendar api are not detected instead...
I sent my screenshot to them to proof the scopes I use is exactly I requested.
[enter image description here][1]

but they just reply me same information like a robot (or it does be?)

Can anyone help me out with this issue?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOEwi.png

Comment: Google track which scopes your application requests when authenticating. Double-check the scopes your application uses via a source code review. I believe you can delete scopes in the console. An alternative is to delete the OAuth Client and create a new one. Then submit for approval.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley , I will try to create a new one :)